# How can I retrieve the last inserted ID from one table and insert it into another table using webmethods?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net

I have several tables and one of those is called Employees.

It is related to several other tables by EmployeeID.

We would like to insert data into Employees table, retrieve the last inserted ID and then immediately insert it into another table, possibly more tables.

I have done this several times before. What is different this time is we are doing so using ajax calls, JSON objects and webmethods.

Inserting records into the Employees table works but retrieving the last inserted ID and attempting to insert it into the other tables is creating an error that says @parameter is required but not supplied.

Is this not possible with ajax calls and webmethods?

This is what I have attempted to do so far that is failing.

Sorry, I tried to keep the code as short as possible while still providing relevant code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0048)http://keniginc.com/WilogIncomeTax/closures.html -->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head id="Head1" runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
    <title>Closure Forms</title>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).on("click", "#btnAdd0", function () { //
                var rowCount = $('.data-contact-person0').length + 1;
                var contactdiv = '<tr class="data-contact-person0">' +
                    '<td><input type="text" style="width:200px;" name="employeename' + rowCount + '" placeholder="Your name..." class="form-control employeename01" /></td>' +
                    '<td><input type="text" style="width:200px;" name="employeetitle' + rowCount + '" placeholder="Your title..." class="form-control employeetitle01" /></td>' +
                    '<td><input type="text" style="width:200px;" name="employeeemail' + rowCount + '" placeholder="Your email address..." class="form-control employeeemail01" /></td>' +
                    '<td style="width:200px;"><button type="button" id="btnAdd0" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary classAdd">Add More</button>' +
                    '<button type="button" id="btnDelete0" class="deleteContact btn btn btn-danger btn-xs">Remove</button></td>' +
                    '</tr>';
                $('#maintable0').append(contactdiv); // Adding these controls to Emp table class
            });

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(document).on("click", "#btnAdd1", function () { //
                    var rowCount = $('.data-contact-person1').length + 1;
                    var contactdiv = '<tr class="data-contact-person1">' +
                        '<td><input type="text" style="width:200px;" name="sourcename' + rowCount + '" placeholder="Name of income source..." class="form-control sourcename01" /></td>' +
                        '<td><input type="text" style="width:200px;" name="sourceaddress' + rowCount + '" placeholder="Address of income source..." class="form-control sourceaddress01" /></td>' +
                        '<td><input type="text" style="width:200px;" name="sourceincome' + rowCount + '" placeholder="Income..." class="form-control sourceincome01" /></td>' +
                        '<td style="width:200px;"><button type="button" id="btnAdd1" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary classAdd">Add More</button>' +
                        '<button type="button" id="btnDelete1" class="deleteContact btn btn btn-danger btn-xs">Remove</button></td>' +
                        '</tr>';
                    $('#maintable1').append(contactdiv); // Adding these controls to Source table class
                });

                              $(document).on("click", ".deleteContact", function () {
                                $(this).closest("tr").remove(); // closest used to remove the respective 'tr' in which I have my controls
                            });

                            function getAllEmpData() {
                                var data = [];
                                $('tr.data-contact-person0').each(function () {
                                    var ename = $(this).find('.employeename01').val();
                                    var etitle = $(this).find('.employeetitle01').val();
                                    var email = $(this).find('.employeeemail01').val();
                                    var alldata = {
                                        'emplName': ename,
                                        'emplTitle': etitle,
                                        'empMail': email
                                    }
                                    data.push(alldata);
                                });
                                console.log(data);
                                return data;
                            }
                            function getAllSourcepData() {
                                var data = [];
                                $('tr.data-contact-person1').each(function () {
                                    var sname = $(this).find('.sourcename01').val();
                                    var saddress = $(this).find('.sourceaddress01').val();
                                    var sincome = $(this).find('.sourceincome01').val();
                                    var alldata = {
                                        'mySource': sname,
                                        'mySAddress': saddress,
                                        'mySIncome': sincome
                                    }
                                    data.push(alldata);
                                });
                                console.log(data);
                                return data;
                            }
                            $("#btnSubmit").click(function (event) {
                                event.preventDefault();
                                var empComplete = false, sourceComplete = false;
                                function checkComplete() {
                                    if (empComplete && sourceComplete) {
                                        $("#result").text("All complete");
                                    }
                                }
                                $("#result").text("");
                                var data = JSON.stringify(getAllEmpData());
                                console.log(data);
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: 'testpost.asp.net/saveEmpData',
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                                    data: JSON.stringify({ 'empdata': data }),
                                    success: function () {
                                        empComplete = true;
                                        checkComplete();
                                    },
                                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                                        alert(xhr.responseText);
                                    }
                                });
                                var data = JSON.stringify(getAllSourcepData());
                                console.log(data);
                                $.ajax({
                                     url: 'testpost.asp.net/saveSourceData',
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                                    data: JSON.stringify({ 'empdata': data }),
                                    success: function () {
                                        sourceComplete = true;
                                        checkComplete();
                                    },
                                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                                        alert(xhr.responseText);
                                    }
                                });
                             });
                        });
              </script>

     <style type="text/css">
    .bs-example{
        margin-left: 250px;
        margin-top: 30px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="bs-example">
    <form id="form1" runat="server" novalidate="novalidate">
        <div class="container">
            <h2>Dynamic Forms</h2>
            <table style="width:55%" id="maintable0">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Employee Name</th>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="data-contact-person0">
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" style="width:200px;" id="employeeename" name="employeename" class="form-control employeename01" placeholder="Your name..."></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" style="width:200px;" name="employeetitle" class="form-control employeetitle01" placeholder="Your title..."></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" style="width:200px;" name="employeeemail" class="form-control employeeemail01" placeholder="Your email address..."></td>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table><br><br>
            <table style="width:73%" id="maintable1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <th>Income</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="data-contact-person1">
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" style="width:200px;" name="sourcename" class="form-control sourcename01" placeholder="Name of income source..."></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" style="width:200px;" name="sourceaddress" class="form-control sourceaddress01" placeholder="Address of income source..."></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" style="width:200px;" name="sourceincome" class="form-control sourceincome01" placeholder="Income..."></td>
                        <td style="width:200px;">
                            <button type="button" id="btnAdd" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary classAdd">Add More</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table><br><br>
            <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md pull-center btn-sm" value="Submit">
            <output id="result"></output>

            <br><br><br>
        </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body></html>


//Codefile

<WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)> _
    Public Shared Function SaveEmpData(empdata As String) As String
        Dim serializedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Employee))(empdata)
        Using con = New SqlConnection(Constr)
            If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                con.Open()
            End If
            '  Dim cmdGetKey As New SqlCommand("Select Max(employeeID) From Employees", con)
            '  Dim ID As Integer = cmdGetKey.ExecuteScalar()

            For Each data As Employee In serializedData
                Using cmd1 = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Employees(EmployeeName,empTitle,email) Values (@ename, @title,@email)")
                    cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ename", data.emplName)
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", data.emplTitle)
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", data.empMail)
                    cmd1.Connection = con
                    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    Dim cmdGetKey As New SqlCommand("SELECT @@IDENTITY", con)
                    Dim ID As Integer = cmdGetKey.ExecuteScalar()
                    HttpContext.Current.Session("empID") = ID
                End Using
            Next
            con.Close()
        End Using
        Return Nothing
    End Function

    <WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)> _
    Public Shared Function SaveSourceData(empdata As String) As String
        Dim serializedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of SourcDetails))(empdata)
        Using con = New SqlConnection(Constr)
            If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                con.Open()
            End If
            '  Dim cmdGetKey As New SqlCommand("Select Max(employeeID) From Employees", con)
            '  Dim ID As Integer = cmdGetKey.ExecuteScalar()

            For Each data As SourcDetails In serializedData
                Using cmd = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO SourceDetails(sourcename, sourceaddress, sourceincome,employeeID) VALUES(@sname, @saddress,@sincome, @ID)")
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sname", data.mySource)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@saddress", data.mySAddress)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sincome", data.mySIncome)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", HttpContext.Current.Session("empID"))
                    '  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedDate", DateTime.Now)
                    cmd.Connection = con
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End Using
            Next
            con.Close()
        End Using
        Return Nothing
    End Function
Public Class Employee
    Public Property emplName() As String
        Get
            Return m_empName
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_empName = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_empName As String
    Public Property emplTitle() As String
        Get
            Return m_empTitle
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_empTitle = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_empTitle As String
    Public Property empMail() As String
        Get
            Return m_empMail
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_empMail = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_empMail As String
End Class
Public Class SourcDetails
    Public Property mySource() As String
        Get
            Return m_mySource
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_mySource = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_mySource As String
    Public Property mySAddress() As String
        Get
            Return m_mySAddress
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_mySAddress = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_mySAddress As String
    Public Property mySIncome() As String
        Get
            Return m_mySIncome
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_mySIncome = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_mySIncome As String

End Class
```

Comment: This sounds like a sql problem.

Comment: No, not all. I don't think you understand my question.

I have done this tons of times and there are tons of online examples of how to do this in SQL. Example, using scope_identity as in : `SET @id=SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

The issue may boil down to passing the ID from one webmethod to another.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have solved the problem.

Since data must be inserted into the Employees table in order to retrieve the last inserted ID to be used later, then setting async to false would delay execution of other webmethods till the SaveEmpData webmethod is executed first.

By doing this, we are able to retrieve the last inserted ID, assign it a session variable, passed it to other webmethods and inserted into other tables.

I will do further testing at this point, it seems to have solved the problem.

Here is how I used the async call:

```
                            var data = JSON.stringify(getAllEmpData());
                            console.log(data);
                            $.ajax({
                                 url: 'testpost.asp.net/saveEmpData',
                                type: 'POST',
                                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                                data: JSON.stringify({ 'empdata': data }),
                                async: false,
                                success: function () {
                                    sourceComplete = true;
                                    checkComplete();
                                },
                                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                                }
                            });
                         });
```